# Saving Populated Listview Items on disk and reloading them when App is launched

Tags: android, listview, serialization, android-contentprovider

In my android application, I have a list view. Each list view item has some text and text and a bitmap. This list is population with content from my back-end each time I start the app.

What I want to do is to save the these populated items onto disk when app is closed, and reload them when app is started next time from the disk. The list can be further populated from back-end. (just like facebook does)

How do I achieve this ? People generally suggest two ways to do this:

- Content Provider and sqlite-db
- Object caching and serialization.

I want to understand what is more appropriate way for the task ? I would appreciate any links/ tuts or code snippets to demonstrate the concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will post my solution.

I found a package that provided kinda middle ground: Easy functionality and simple retrieval: www.rushorm.com

It allows for queries too, as well as storage of bitmaps and large texts.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my best answer to this. Both techniques will work, no doubt.
The advantage of using SQL database is that you can retrieve a group of data or records by simply forming the query string. The database of course can store lots of data.

The object caching/serialization or files technique tend to have limited data. They are not naturally made to be queried with group matching (like the **SQL Where** clause). I know you can use XML schema files but then performance may be an issue. 
If you only have few data, then I have used XML files to support query relational search.

Comment: I do not want query at this point. Merely saving and loading on next start. How do I go on about it ? Any particular package (Object has a bitmap too) ? When do I save to disk: onPause or onStop ?

Comment: @silent_grave, Your latest question is different, though more specific, than your original question. Your original question, I thought, was more philosophical on design. If you think my answer is helpful, click on the up-arrow icon, and you can post another question. I'll check with tags of android-fragment and listview. Good luck.

Comment: Just to answer your latest question briefly...You could simply place all your images (png) on proper folders. And then iterate through all the folders for your images. If you do some research on your design, then you will attract more attention and respect in the community.  Another, I don't understand why you brought up onPause or onStop. Just post another question for that one.